# determine the marker that navigate to activity xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I'm working on xamarin.forms application custom map shows markers from the database when the user click on pin show 
***custom info window*** then if he clicks on this 
info window navigates to another activity show more information.
I used the sample on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin) and cannot code navigate from pin to activity with all data to show in this activity

[image]

I need help, please

Comment: if you have any relevant code, you should provide it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by `MessagingCenter`

There is running GIF.

[image]

In `CustomMapRenderer`

You should send the message with `MessageCenter`.

```
  void OnInfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var customPin = GetCustomPin(e.Marker);
        if (customPin == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customPin.Url))
        {
            var url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(customPin.Url);
            MessagingCenter.Send<App, string>(App.Current as App, "OpenPage", customPin.Address + "");
        }
    }
```

When you Subscribe this message, you can open the navigationpage.Note:You can send information by arg.

```
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, string>(App.Current, "OpenPage", (snd, arg) =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new DetailsInfo(arg)));
            });
        });
```

There is article about how to use `MessagingCenter`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

Here is my demo. You could refer to it.

https://github.com/851265601/MapUseMessageCenter

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.